# Returning Array of objects using RxJS map operator

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I have one third Party API which returns data as below - It has been called from Angular Service using `HttpClient`.

```
const someObject = {

    employees:[   

        {name:"XYZ",age:30},
        {name:"ABC",age:28},
    ]
}
```

Now I have one `interface` with structure as below -

```
interface EmployeeData{

   campus:{

     property1:string;
     property2:string;

   };
   details:{

     name:string;
     age:number

   }
}
```

So `EmployeeData.details` exactly mimics `someObject.employees` structure

Now I want to return data from my service as below -

```
getData():Observable<EmployeeData[]>{

}
```

So , employees **array from someObject** should map to **EmployeeData.details**

and this should be returned as `EmployeeData[].`

How can I achieve this ?

I have tried below approach but it is giving different results.

```
getData():Observable<EmployeeData[]> {


     return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(

        tap(value => console.log(value)),
        map(data => data.employees),
        map(employees =>{

              return employees.map(employee =>{

                return{

                    details:{
                        name:employee.name,
                        age:employee.age,

                    }                       

                }           
            }
          }
        ) 

    }
```

What it returns is -

```
details:{}
details:{}
```

But what I want is :

```
{
    details:{}
}
{
    details:{}
}
```

Can anybody please help here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type the function with `Observable<EmployeeData>`, your returned Observable must contain an array of objects implementing the `EmployeeData` interface, meaning that you will need to define them fully, not just the `details` property.

If you can't define all properties at this time, you have to use a type assertion with the `as` keyword. Be aware that you will lose type safety and might run into errors because missing properties will be undefined.

```
getData(): Observable<EmployeeData[]> {
  return this.http.get<any>(url)
    .pipe(
      map(data => data.employees),
      map(employees => employees.map(employee => ({ details: employee } as EmployeeData)))
    );
}
```

See it in action here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-msd6ym

Comment: I've updated my answer, it's working just fine, see the attached stackblitz link.